# Proof that $\displaystyle\iint\dfrac{\partial^2 \xi(x,y)}{\partial x\partial x}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x=\xi(x,y)+xc_1 +c_2$

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

Can anyone exaplain me why:

$$
\iint\dfrac{\partial^2 \xi(x,y)}{\partial x\partial x}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x=\xi(x,y)+xc_1 +c_2
$$
?

I would like to have a simple proof if is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ twice.

Comment: I was about to say "thanks Sherlock."

Comment: I'm sorry my bad! Now is the definitive edit!

Comment: @FormlessCloud The hint still applies.

Comment: I'm so retarded! Thank you!

Comment: @FormlessCloud No problem. I've failed worse than you did now, don't worry.